# Do I need to close IAsyncOperation?

Tags: asynchronous, windows-runtime, winrt-async

In WinRT, do I need to call `Close()` on `IAsyncOperation<T> ^` objects? Either the the operation initiating code, or in the completion handler? If not, why is it there?

Comment: Its base class IAsyncInfo has `Close()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.iasyncinfo.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your syntax, you're using C++/CX.

For C++/CX, IAsyncOperation::Close is automatically called in the destructor, so you do not need to explicitly call it.

For JS, you must explicitly call .close().

For C#, it's projected as IDisposable, so a using() statement is appropriate.

Comment: Good to know. Where should I call it in JS - from the initiating code or from the completion handler?

Comment: Whenever you're done with the operation & don't need the results.  This can happen in the completion handler.